# What is the recommended number of consumers per group in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What is the recommended number of consumers per group in Kafka? Basically, I have 400 topics, i want to consume from in my group. I noticed in my experimentation that I if I 1 consumer to consumer all 400 topics, it works. But if I create 1 consumer for each topic in a single consumer group, I am not able to receive any messages.

EDIT:
I found that some consumers are able to receive messages during the poll loop but not all them. My guess is that they are being removed from the consumer group due to missing heartbeat.

From the logs it looks like after few minutes some consumer are not able to send any heartbeats because the group is always rebalancing:

```
[2019-03-08 07:42:36,769] INFO [Consumer clientId=jira_con-chow-test-69, groupId=chow] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2019-03-08 07:42:39,671] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=jira_con-chow-test-69, groupId=chow] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator mwkafka-prod-02.tbd:9092 (id: 2147483641 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
....
```

I want to know practically what is the appropriate number of consumers that should join a group. Or Am I interpreting this problem incorrectly and I should look at something else.

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: 400 topics or partitions?

Comment: 400 topics each with 1 partition

Answer (score 0):

The ideal equation is:
**number of partitions = number of consumers in a consumer group.**

Consider, a topic t with 50 partitions has a consumer group of 10 consumers, then it will (at first) start consuming 10 partitions only. After reaching last offset in a partition, the consumers start consuming other partitions of the topic t.

For more details [Kafka Consumer](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/)

Another useful [post](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html)

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying I should create 400 consumer groups for 400 topics? But I can use 1 consumer (1 consumer group) to consume from all 400 topics.

Comment: Not consumer groups, but the number of consumers in a consumer groups

Comment: I have 400 topics each with 1 partition. so how many consumers is ideal?

Comment: For better parallelism, I would suggest (2 of many):
 -1 consumer group with 400 consumers.
OR
 -400 consumer groups with 1 consumer

Comment: this is what i see when i use 400 consumer with 1 group: "After few minutes some consumer are not able to send any heartbeats because the group is always rebalancing"